# Permission from military when hiking in Israel

Tags: trails

When hiking in Israel I've seen some trails that had information on them to contact [IDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Israel_Defense_Forces) first for permission before going on them.

How I'm supposed to get the permission? How much in advance you have to apply? Are there any specific reasons you might be denied the permission?

[image: Trail sign with IDF approval info]

Comment: A UN countries list high points peakbagger friend (we're going on a trip soon) actually went to Mount Hermon (the true summit of Syria) in spring of 2019. He was one of the lucky people who ducked Syrian patrols with a local guide, crossed a mine field, and disregarded Nepalese UN soldiers in an outpost on the Lebanon/Syria border along the ridge. That's why the whole area needs military clearance. It's a damn war zone. Yeah, my friend is a lunatic.

Answer (score 4):

According to [this thread](https://www.tapatalk.com/groups/israeltrail/viewtopic.php?f=40&t=687&p=2244&hilit=havushit#p2244) on Tapatalk, the Mt Havushit trail is the starting point for the Golan trail. It seems from the map in the thread that if you start or want to climb Mt Havushit, that this is on the border with Israel and Syria and Lebanon (not Palestine, as anatolyg pointed out) and as such is likely to cross the "ceasefire line" (see picture below) The thread indicated that the trail normally starts by the gates and Hermon site parking lots (see pic) on Route 98 rather than at the top of Mt Havushit.

[image: Mt Havushit area]

The following details were provided:

> Only if you plan to start at 2,000 meters and hike a beautiful 4 km additional section, from 
>   Mt. Havushit, you  must contact the IDF, at least two days in advance, and let them know about 
>   your plan.
>
> Contact tel.: 04-6966207. The IDF declines your request, start the hike at the beginning 
>   of the GT, Day 1.

Comment: It's near the Israel/Syria/Lebanon triple point, not anywhere close to Palestine (in the sense of 21st century). So the border is pretty well-established, impossible to cross it by mistake.

Comment: Thanks, I'll edit that in. I just assumed Palestine from the ceasefire line.